# The word document of the docx suffix generated by freemarker cannot display the image on the iphone

Tags: java, ios, iphone, freemarker, docx

The word document of the docx suffix generated by freemarker cannot display the image on the iphone. But after some minor modifications in the office, such as adding a space and saving, you can see the picture correctly on the iPhone.

I want to generate a wrod document that can display images on my iPhone.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dklTB.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKXrk.jpg)
https://gitee.com/wahnn/JavaUtilsProject/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sl/utils/office/word  it's my code reference.

Comment: https://gitee.com/wahnn/JavaUtilsProject/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sl/utils/office/word        Code reference

Comment: Hello, Consider adding more info to the question. Is there some example code or stack trace we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead using xdocreport (which can use freemarker under the covers) which ought to be able to get the image rels etc right for you.